# difference meaning between 'the role of a teacher' and 'the role of the teacher'

Tags: articles

> difference meaning between 'the role of a teacher' and 'the role of the teacher'

The only difference is 'a' and 'the' after teacher.

Is there any difference in usage or do we have to have a context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning if it refers to teachers in general. If the context is a particular classroom and teacher, it needs to be *the*.